# FireBreath FB::PluginWindowWin include problem

Tags: plugins, directx, winsock2, firebreath

I tried to follow the steps in the answer of
[Directx control in browser plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6097069/directx-control-in-browser-plugin)

but when I added the solution mentioned in
http://colonelpanic.net/2010/11/firebreath-tips-drawing-on-windows/
FireBreath Tips: Drawing on Windows

"1.Make your plugin object windows specific

change the type of the event source specified in EVENTTYPE_CASE to FB::PluginWindowWin (as well as the type in the handlers) and you will have your object cast in the way you need it."

I got 119 errors, all are in winsock2.h file, which I included in other file,
saying redefinition, different linkage. what to do?

Thanks, Sara

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a general problem occures when one tries to include windows.h and winsock2.h.

windows.h includes winsock.h itself, therefore, if you include winsock2.h after it, several redefinition conflicts arise.

Solution: include "winsock2.h" first.

Comment: If you include "win_common.h" as the first include in your file as I specified in my first answer you wouldn't have this issue, since win_common.h *does* include winsock2.h first and makes sure that your basic includes are in the correct order... in fact, that's its whole purpose in life.

Comment: Well, It didn't work... There was a whole mess in the includes, I had to order them carefully in all the files, which require the "winsock2" be the first of all.

Comment: oh.. my mistake. I guess FireBreath doesn't use winsock2 and thus you're actually hitting a different (but very similar sounding) problem than I experienced. sorry :-/

Answer (score 0):

did you add the #include "Win/PluginWindowWin.h"?

another thing that can help that is #include "win_common.h" early in the file.  The include order of certain windows headers and winsock matters, so that can cause this issue if they get out of order.

Comment: I did include "Win/PluginWindowWin.h". I tried to include "win_common.h" but that doesn't help. the only thing helps is to inclue "Win/PluginWindowWin.h" in the cpp, which I don't want to.

Comment: Wait; why don't you want to include PluginWindowWin in the cpp? If the class isn't defined then it certainly isn't going to work... Also, did you include "win_common.h" as the *first include*?

Comment: Yes, I added it as the first include. I'm stuck also in my other question http://stackoverflow.com/q/6030417/487305 until I solve this.